# SQL SUM from three columns not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an expression combining two queries, which works fine

```
SELECT FinalIncoming.ID, FinalIncoming.ProductCode, FinalIncoming.ProductName, 
  FinalIncoming.StandardCost, FinalIncoming.OnHand, FinalOutgoiing.Incoming, 
  FinalIncoming.Outgoing
FROM FinalIncoming INNER JOIN FinalOutgoiing ON FinalIncoming.ID = FinalOutgoiing.ID;
```

But whenever I try to SUM up the last three columns with:

```
Sum([FinalIncoming.OnHand]+[FinalIncoming.Outgoing]-[FinalOutgoiing.Incoming])
```

Access comes up with an error saying `Your query does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of an aggregate function.`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I've tried rewriting the SUM expression in different ways, and with aliases, but it comes up with the same error.

*FYI: I know the `Outgoiing` query is misspelled.*

Comment: Show us the whole query that goes wrong!

Comment: If you select both just columns and also have aggregate functions, you need a GROUP BY clause!

Comment: Please use group by clause at the end of your query and keep all columns in group by clause except columns used in sum function.

Comment: @jarlh I tried it with a GROUP BY clause, but it would come with two rows for ones with Incoming and Outgoing and not joining, So I did an INNER JOIN which put each row and the end, and just selected what I need

Comment: @cfleming93 Please provide us sample of input and expected output so we will understand what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: @sagi I'm not getting an output because of the error, I'm looking to do an Inventory backlog, so going back to a selected date, for products bought/sold after that date it will update the OnHand total (plus outgoing, minus incoming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the keyword in your error message is "as part of an aggregate"

ACCESS SQL requires all columns to be involved in an aggregation when you use the group by function.

so your query would be:

```
SELECT FinalIncoming.ID, FinalIncoming.ProductCode, FinalIncoming.ProductName, 
      first(FinalIncoming.StandardCost) as firstCostValue, SUM(FinalIncoming.OnHand + FinalOutgoiing.Incoming - FinalIncoming.Outgoing) AS something
    FROM FinalIncoming INNER JOIN FinalOutgoiing ON FinalIncoming.ID = FinalOutgoiing.ID
GROUP BY FinalIncoming.ID, FinalIncoming.ProductCode, FinalIncoming.ProductName;
```